# Can't turn on IE compatibility mode with IE hacks on

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When I use IE hacks the compatibility mode is still on an available. But if I remove the hacks, it works as expected.

Hacks (Does not work)

```
<!doctype html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie6 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie ie7 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie ie8 lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

No Hacks (Works fine)

```
<!doctype html>

<html class="no-js ie ie8 lt-ie9" lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

I for the life me can't figure out why the compat mode wont work with the hacks on. I am using  IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch IE8 to the quirks mode, right? The content attribute means which compatible mode you want to use. It does **not** mean which IE version using the quirks mode.

Try this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```